# How to implement automatic date in the subject for particular sender in the Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need an automation feasibility for data changing in my subject and body of message.

For example,

**subject**-update required 15-July-2015

**body of message**

xxxxxxxxxxxxx 14-july-2015

Note-In subject my date has to be today's date but in Body of message I need previous day date.

Can it be automation for this.

Comment: are you trying to apply this changes when msg is received?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class if you need to modify the outcoming emails.

```
 Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 

 Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
  Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application  
 End Sub 

 Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
  Dim prompt As String 
  prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
  If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
    Cancel = True  
  End If  
 End Sub
```

In case if you need to modify incoming emails you need to handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Note that this behavior has changed from earlier versions of the event when the EntryIDCollection contained a list of comma-delimited Entry IDs of all the items received in the Inbox since the last time the event was fired.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the NameSpace.GetItemFromID method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.